# Creating a polygon that shows the specific elevation above a river using a DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, elevation, area, arcgis-10.5

My goal is to determine the possible area covered by interpreted Tertiary drainages.  To keep my example simple, I have a DEM and a River polyline.  I would like to see the area a polygon (or raster) would cover if it was 100 feet above my River polyline.  Being that the river decreases in elevation as it drains, the polygon would cover most of the valley but some might spill over the top and could possibly show where old drainages might have occurred.  I have attempted to google this but have not found anything.  Seems simple enough to do.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

I am using ArcMap 10.5

Comment: Basically I am trying to determine the flood plain if the water was 100 feet above the valley bottom over the course of the river.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: This post may be relevant: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272457/use-buffer-from-idw-3d-analyst-for-flood-spread/272460#272460

Comment: Sorry I am using ArcMap 10.5

Comment: I tried the post you suggested but it did not work